# C++ using <template> in .h

Tags: c++

I want to create a function that is

while t is `template<typename T>`

```
string myFunction(T t) {
    string str1;
    //some computation with t
    return str1();
}
```

So in my `.h` file, I do something like

```
class myClass {
    private:
    //some variable
    public:
    string myFunction(T); 
}
```

and of course it gives an error saying "what is T?"

What should I do to make `myFunction` able to take a `T`?

Answer (score 3):

Make a member function template:

```
class Foo {
    template<typename T>
    string myFunction(T t)
    {
    }
};
```

or, make a class template:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
    string myFunction(T t)
    {
    }
};
```

Whatever makes sense for your case. If you're defining the function outside of class, then:

```
class Foo {
    template<typename T>
    string myFunction(T);
};

template<typename T>
string Foo::myFunction(T t)
{
}
```

for member function template, or

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
    string myFunction(T);
};

template<typename T>
string Foo<T>::myFunction(T t)
{
}
```

for class template.